# Configure Apache to allow the access for the specific URL under VPN

Tags: apache-2.2, security, vpn

Here is the case, I want to configure the Apache server so that some of the URLs can be accessed under VPN and some of them should be accessible with/without VPN.

Here is my scenario

**Without VPN**

- User goes to http://example.com/some/url - should be allowed to access
- User goes to http://example.com/vpn/restricted/url - shouldn't be allowed to access

**With VPN**

- User goes to http://example.com/some/url - should be allowed to access
- User goes to http://example.com/vpn/restricted/url - should be allowed to access

What are my options?

**EDIT:**

I don't have info on how the VPN is configured, I can figure it out, but I would like to know the details of the questions that I should be asking my people network. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: In your network, how does VPN traffic differ from other traffic?

Comment: @ShaneMadden - can you be specific? I am not a n/w expert but trying to see if this can be configured via Apache.

Comment: Can you provide any details about how your environment is set up?  It's difficult to provide specific advice without some additional information from you, as there are a million different ways that a VPN might be implemented.  Are the clients or remote endpoints on the other side of a VPN?  If so, then @lVlint67's answer is exactly what you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

At least you are concise.

Take a look at [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html)

```
Description:    Controls which hosts can access an area of the server
Syntax:  Allow from all|host|env=[!]env-variable [host|env=[!]env-variable] ...
Context:    directory, .htaccess
Override:   Limit
Status: Base
Module: mod_authz_host
Compatibility:  Support for negating env=env-variable was added in 2.2.10
```